# matplotlib - Plot salva cortado

Tags: python, matplotlib

Ao salvar o meu gráfico ele fica com um recorte a esquerda em cima dos nomes por ser largo. Como arrumo isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
cmap = cc.cm['kbc']
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = ranking_members.rating.min(), vmax = ranking_members.rating.max())

plt.barh(ranking_members.name, ranking_members.members, color = cc.cm['kbc'](norm(ranking_members.rating.values)))

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap = cmap, norm = norm)
sm.set_array([])
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm)
cbar.ax.get_yaxis().labelpad = 15
cbar.set_label('Nota', rotation = 270)

plt.title('Ranking de Popularidade')
plt.xlabel('Número de Membros')
plt.ylabel('Anime')

plt.savefig('C:\\Users\\msamu\\Desenvolvimento\\Data Analysis\\Python\\My Anime List\\Plots\\ranking_members.png', dpi = 300)
```

Comment: Não tenho certeza se funciona pois não há como testar, mas ao adicionar `bbox_inches='tight'` como terceiro parâmetro (após dpi=300) da função `savefig()`, deve funcionar.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Ao salvar seu gráfico basta você adicionar mais um parâmetro, chamado `bbox_inches`, a sua função `savefig()`. Alterando:

```
plt.savefig('C:\\caminho\\...\\ranking_members.png', dpi = 300)
```

Por:

```
plt.savefig('C:\\caminho\\...\\ranking_members.png', dpi = 300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

A propriedade `bbox_inches='tight'` remove todo o espaço extra em branco que há em torno da figura, ele não reorganiza a sua figura, mas para um solução rápida funciona. Caso deseje alterar mais configurações para obter exatamente oque deseja, pode utilizar o [Tight Layout](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html).

[Pergunta relacionada no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16039013/9671639)